# Joining two tables with defaultscope in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

Here is my students model

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array('with' => array('StudentDetails'));
}
```

`StudentDetails` is another model. I would like to get the results from both the table always.
So I tried defaultscope but getting error as

```
Relation "Students" is not defined in active record class "StudentDetails".
```

How can I use defaultscope properly

Comment: can you add studentdetails model code in question?

Comment: You need to have both side relations defined for this to work.. i.e. relation from student->StudentDetails and also StudentDetails->Student as well.. are both relations defined?

Comment: @Manquer I did not defined in studentDetails model. So in studentDetails table also I should have defaultScope() right?

Comment: it depends on the type of relation  and use case i guess, Actually I don't see why you need to use "with" in defaultScope at all if the relation is defined, the related object is loaded as and when it is referenced( yii supports lazy loading by default)